# RFID authentication

Tags: python, rfid

I'm using an RFID tag and I have written auth1 on the tag. I want to use it as an authentication tag. So if you scan the tag and the content of the tag is the same as the variable auth1 you get a return 'Access Granted'. And if the content of the tag isn't the same as the variable auth1 it returns 'Access Denied'.

Below the code I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()
auth0 = 'Access Denied'
auth1 = 'Access Granted'

try:
        id, text = reader.read()
        print(id)
        if text == auth1:
            print(auth1)
        else:
          return auth0
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

I used the code above and I tried to let it read the content of the tag (reader.read()) and if the text equals `auth1` print `auth1`, otherwise return `auth0`. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the text on the tag to the variable auth1, which has a value of "Acces Granted"

```
auth1 = 'Access Granted'
if text == auth1:

-> if text == "Access Granted"
```

So if your tag has "auth1" on it, you should compare to that.

```
if text == "auth1":
```

Comment: I changed it to this, but it's still not working. It only prints access denied:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()
auth0 = 'Access Denies'
auth1 = 'Access Granted'

try:
        id, text = reader.read()
        print(id)
        
        if text == 'auth1':
            print(auth1)
        else:
           print(auth0)
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()

Comment: Did you check if the text on the tag is in fact "auth1"

Comment: yea 'auth1' is in fact on the tag

Comment: Is it also being returned by `reader.read()` ? If the check fails then `text` is not equal to `"auth1"`

Comment: No where would i need to put that in the code?

Comment: Try adding `print(text)` before the if statement so you can see what the value is. Or even better, use a debugger.